# Can't utilize TChart's ChartController in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, teechart

I am trying to create the toolbar (ChartController) for my Tchart in WPF.
I see the Forms example, But I can not create the objects needed in WPF.

```
    private Steema.TeeChart.Commander commander1;
    private Steema.TeeChart.Editor editor1;
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;
            ...
```

Thanks...

Comment: This question is now answered on Steema's support forums and can be viewed [here](http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=14588&p=64320#p64320)